Proof of Existence of Supremum of Distances in Compact Subsets of Metric Spaces in $R^2$
I have some questions about the solution to the following problem about compactness in real analysis.
This question differs from Showing that a compact set in $R^2$ achieves it supremum because it pertains to a different solution approach.
Problem Statement
Let $(X, \partial)$ be a metric space and $K$ a compact subset of $X$. Show that there exist $x_0, y_0 \in K$ such that
$$
\partial(x_0, y_0) = \sup \{\partial(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\}.
$$
Solution

Define the Function:
For a fixed $x \in K$, define a function $f_x : K \to \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$
   f_x(y) = \partial(x, y).
   $$
Since $\partial$ is a metric, $f_x$ is a continuous function.

Claim: The Set $A = \{\partial(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\}$ is Compact.
Since $K$ is compact, for any fixed $x \in K$, the function $f_x(y) = \partial(x, y)$ achieves its maximum and minimum values on $K$ due to the extreme value theorem (as $f_x$ is continuous).
Therefore, for each $x \in K$, there exists a point $y_x \in K$ such that $\partial(x, y_x)$ is the maximum distance from $x$ to any point in $K$.
By considering all $x \in K$, we can define:
$$
   A = \{\partial(x, y) \mid x, y \in K\}.
   $$
$A$ is bounded because $K$ is compact and the metric $\partial$ ensures that distances are finite. Since $A$ is also closed (as $\partial$ is continuous), it follows that $A$ is compact.

Finding the Maximum Value:
Let $a = \sup A$, i.e., the maximum value in $A$. By the definition of $\sup$, there exists a sequence $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ such that:
$$
   \partial(x_n, y_n) \to a \text{ as } n \to \infty.
   $$
Since $K$ is compact, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ converging to some point $x_0 \in K$. Similarly, the sequence $\{y_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{y_{k_n}\}$ converging to some point $y_0 \in K$.

Conclusion About Compactness and Convergence:
We can assume that $(x_{k_n}, y_{k_n}) \to (x_0, y_0)$ where both $x_0, y_0 \in K$. By the continuity of $\partial$, we have:
$$
   \partial(x_0, y_0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{k_n}) = a.
   $$
Therefore, $\partial(x_0, y_0)$ achieves the maximum value of $\partial(x, y)$ over all $x, y \in K$, which completes the proof.
Proof of the Claim:
Let $a_n = \partial(x_n, y_{x_n}) \subseteq A$. Since $K$ is compact, we can find a subsequence $x_{k_n}$ such that $x_{k_n} \xrightarrow{\partial} x_0 \in K$. Since $\{y_{x_{k_n}}\} \subseteq K$, by passing to a further subsequence, we may assume that $y_{x_{k_n}} \to y_0 \in K$. Then $y_0 = y_{x_0}$.
Note first that $\partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) \to \partial(x_0, y_0)$. Indeed,
$$
   \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_n}) \leq \partial(x_{k_n}, x_0) + \partial(x_0, y_0) + \partial(x_0, x_{k_n}),
   $$
leading to:
$$
   \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) - \partial(x_0, y_0) \leq \partial(x_{k_n}, x_0) + \partial(y_0, y_{x_{k_n}}).
   $$
Similarly, we get:
$$
   \partial(x_0, y_0) - \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) \leq \partial(x_{k_n}, x_0) + \partial(y_0, y_{x_{k_n}}),
   $$
which implies:
$$
   |\partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) - \partial(x_0, y_0)| \leq \partial(x_{k_n}, x_0) + \partial(y_0, y_{x_{k_n}}).
   $$
By the construction of $\{y_{x_{k_n}}\}$, we have:
$$
   \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) \geq \partial(x_{k_n}, y) \quad \forall y \in K \Rightarrow \partial(x_0, y_0) \geq \partial(x_0, y) \quad \forall y \in K.
   $$
Thus, $y_{x_0} = y_0$. Therefore:
$$
   a_{k_n} = \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) \to \partial(x_0, y_{x_0}) \in A,
   $$
and we conclude that $A$ is compact.


My questions
I understand that since $K$ is compact every sequence has a convergent subsequence and that therefore the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ converges to some point $x_0 \in K$. Similarly, the sequence $\{y_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{y_{k_n}\}$ converging to some point $y_0 \in K$. But how does it follow that $\partial(x_0, y_0)$ achieves the supremum over all x,y, since $x_0$ is simply an arbitrary point that some sequence converges to?
I also do not properly understand this part:
By the construction of $\{y_{x_{k_n}}\}$, we have:
$$
   \partial(x_{k_n}, y_{x_{k_n}}) \geq \partial(x_{k_n}, y) \quad \forall y \in K \Rightarrow \partial(x_0, y_0) \geq \partial(x_0, y) \quad \forall y \in K.
   $$
Thus, $y_{x_0} = y_0$.
How do we know that the further subsequence $(y_{x_{k_n}})$ must converge to $y_0$, which is the point that maximizes the distance from $x_0$? We know that $(y_{x_{k_n}})$ must converge since every subsequence in a compact set converges but I am not sure why it converges to $y_0$. Does this mean if you take any further subsequence $(y_{x_{k_n}})$, it has to converge to $y_0$?

What does $y_{x_{n_k}}$ mean? After all, $x_{n_k}$ is an element of $X$ rather than a natural number.

The expression $x_{k_n}$ represents a specific element within a sequence ${x_n}$ that is indexed by $k_n$. Essentially, $k_n$ is a subsequence of natural numbers, and $x_{k_n} \in X$ denotes a particular point in $X$.
When we write $y_{x_{k_n}}$, it signifies that for the specific point $x_{k_n}$ in $X$, there is an associated point $y_{x_{k_n}} \in K$. This $y_{x_{k_n}}$ is chosen such that it satisfies a certain condition (e.g., it may be a point that maximizes the distance $\partial(x_{k_n}, y)$ over all $y \in K$).

So, although $x_{k_n}$ is  an element of $X$, $y_{x_{k_n}}$ represents the point in $K$ that is associated with $x_{k_n}$.

You just wrote that $y_{x_{k_n}}$ is “an associated point” with respect to $x_{k_n}$. That means nothing.
